# [Pdb results attached]Constraint works in Table B 'matching query does not exist' in Table A - Python/Django

Tags: sql, django, constraints, django-queryset, multiple-databases

I have several tables as below, which was created according to a `third-party system`, application also runs under the database of this system(oracle).

Constraint failed in `Table`A, but it works in `Table B`, supposed I want to display e.name in `Table B` with code of `b.c.d.e.name`, the fronted page displayed exact data, and fronted page displayed `None` in `Table A` with code of `a.b.c.d.e.name`,

```
class A(models.Model):
    a_id = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True)
    b = models.OneToOneField('B', models.DO_NOTHING, related_name='+')

class B(models.Model):
    b_id = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True)
    c = models.OneToOneField('C', models.DO_NOTHING, related_name='+')

class C(models.Model):
    c_id = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True)
    d = models.OneToOneField('D', models.DO_NOTHING, related_name='+')

class D(models.Model):
    d_id = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True)
    e = models.OneToOneField('E', models.DO_NOTHING, related_name='+')

class E(models.Model):
    e_id = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=64)
```

Results of pdb as below:

```
(Pdb) B.objects.using('third_party_db').get(c__d__e__name="Dog")
*** general.models.B.MultipleObjectsReturned: get() returned more than one B -- it returned 1673!
(Pdb) A.objects.using('third_party_db').get(b__c__d__e__name="Dog")
*** general.models.A.DoesNotExist: A matching query does not exist.
(Pdb) A.objects.using('third_party_db').get(b__c__pk=1)
*** general.models.A.DoesNotExist: A matching query does not exist.
(Pdb) A.objects.using('third_party_db').get(b__f__pk=1)
*** general.models.A.MultipleObjectsReturned: get() returned more than one A -- it returned 18!
```

Comment: What exactly is the problem? It perfectly makes sense that the queries can return multiple elements, or none at all.

Comment: I want to display data of `A.B.C.D.E.name` on fronted page, but I can only display A.B objects and B.C.D.E.name, not what I want

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem You still don't understand right? 